# How to get data from 2d array in mixins (Jade/Pug)?

Tags: pug

I am new to Jade/Pug, and trying to create a table through mixins. But when I pass my array to mixin which creates a row, I get the following:

#### created table (wrong data in the rows)

[image: created table (wrong data in the rows)]

So the question is how can I get the right data?

#### Here is my jade code

```
mixin row(items)  
  tr
  each item, index in items
    td= item

mixin th(items)  
  each item, index in items
    th= item  

mixin table(tableData, tableHeader)
  table    
    each header, index in tableHeader      
      +th(header)      
    each row, index in tableData         
      +row(row)    
  
- var tableHeader = [{name: "Fruits"}, {name: "Vegetables"}, {name: "Berries"}]  

- var node = [[{name: "apple"}, {name: "cucumber"}, {name: "strawberry"}], [{name: "orange"}, {name: "tomato"}, {name: "blueberry"}]]

+table(node, tableHeader)
```

I have already tried to write

```
td #{item}
```

but it doesn't work too

Answer (score 1):

The data is arrays of objects, which is why you're seeing `[object Object]` in the compiled code. Two options:

#### Access the name property of each array.

Since `item` in your example is something like `{name: 'foo'}`, use `#{item.name}` instead of `#{item}`

#### Store data as array of strings instead of objects

If you set `node` to `node = ['apple', 'cucumber', ... ]` instead of what you have, just `#{item}` will work without issue.